# How to invoke https service from phonegap for BB Z10

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10

How to invoke https service from phonegap for BB Z10

I am using phonegap 2.1 and in config.xml i have added access origin also

access origin="http://xxxxx/*" subdomains="true"

but still service request is not fired to server. where as if i use http instead of https its working.

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

According to [whitelist guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide), you do not have to include wildcard `/*` for the path section of the url. Just the domain `http://xxxxx` is enough.

Comment: as of now we r trying to invoke a service via backbone js.. i suspect whether backbone js is fully functional on BB browser.. the same is working fine in android & ios platforms..